# Bulk rename file names in Drive Folder with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need to rename image files in a Google Drive folder

I have a Google Sheet with 2 columns, old name and new name

I would like to rename the files within the same folder using AppsScript and the sheet content as input

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

If I understand this correctly, you want change names of the files in a Drive folder according to some sheet data (current name is in column A, and new name is in column B).

#### Solution:

If that's the case, I'd suggest the following:

- Get all sheet values with `getRange().getValues()`.
- Iterate through all value rows.
- For each row, find the folder files whose name is the value from column A, using [Folder.getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbynamename).
- Set the new file name with [File.setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename).

#### Code snippet:

```
const SPREADSHEET_ID = "SPREADSHEET_ID"; // Change according to your preferences
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Change according to your preferences
const FOLDER_ID = "DRIVE_FOLDER_ID"; // Change according to your preferences

function changeFolderNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // If there's no header row, use "A:B" instead
  values.forEach(row => {
    const [oldName, newName] = row;
    const fileIter = folder.getFilesByName(oldName);
    while (fileIter.hasNext()) {
      const file = fileIter.next();
      file.setName(newName);
    }
  });
}
```